# Are Github Actions Steps independent?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, github, github-actions, homebrew

I am currently writing a new GH Action Workflow. For installing our pre-requisites I want to use `brew`. I am installing brew in one step and want to use it in another step. As far as I can see in the official docs, steps run in the same environment, thus after installing it, it should be possible to use it in another steps.

I am installing brew in the first step, use it in the second, but there it cannot be found. If I put the installation and the usage in the same step, everything works.

But why does the following not work - So In the second step it cannot find `brew`, eventho I installed it in step 1?

```
name: Tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
jobs:
  tests:
    name: "Run tests"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Install homebrew
        run: |
            /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
            (echo; echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"') >> /root/.profile
            eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
            sudo apt-get update -y
            sudo apt-get install build-essential -y
            brew install gcc
      - name: Install prerequisites
        run: |
            brew install kubernetes-cli k3d istioctl cmctl
```

I am a bit confused since in the step `Install homebrew`, it knows brew after installing it, but in the step `Install prerequisites` it does not find it anymore.
Thus, if ich change the steps to

```
- name: Install homebrew
        run: |
            /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
            (echo; echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"') >> /root/.profile
            eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
            sudo apt-get update -y
            sudo apt-get install build-essential -y
            brew install gcc
            brew install kubernetes-cli k3d istioctl cmctl
```

Everything works as expected - but WHY?

Log Error output:

```
[Tests/Run tests]     docker exec cmd=[bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail /var/run/act/workflow/2] user= workdir=
| /var/run/act/workflow/2: line 2: brew: command not found
[Tests/Run tests]   ❌  Failure - Main Install prerequisites
[Tests/Run tests] exitcode '127': command not found, please refer to https://github.com/nektos/act/issues/107 for more information
[Tests/Run Watcher E2E tests]   Job failed
```

To test it locally, I am using [act](https://github.com/nektos/act), with `act -j tests --container-architecture linux/amd64"`

Comment: Each job runs in a different runner and each `run` is a different shell. The installations are there but the env vars and `source` are not preserved. For setting paths after installation, you can use `GITHUB_PATH`. See [Adding a system path](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-system-path) or you can run the `eval` step again.

Comment: Also, observe `--noprofile --norc` flags with [`bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html). Setting paths to profile files won't work. See [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].shell`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell) for more details.

Comment: I know that jobs run in different runners, but those are just two steps, not two jobs. Thus, they are running in the same runner

Comment: That was not the point actually, the rest was i.e. "each `run` is a different shell".

Comment: Notice that [homebrew is already installed](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#package-management) on ubuntu-22.04 runners.

Comment: I'm not sure if act errors are representative of the "real thing".